# Matplotlib animate over an image

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to animate a bunch of constantly updating points over an image (imagine making a plotted dot move diagonally across some image).  I've looked at the animate examples here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/dynamic_image.html, but I'm not sure how to keep the same image while clearing out all previous dots, then redrawing them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to clear the figure between every frame

```
#initial data 
ln, = ax.plot(x,y)
#...some loop code
    ln.set_xdata(new_x)
    ln.set_ydata(new_y)
```

Can you show some code of what you have tried, it will make it easier to give a more concrete answer.

Also see: [using matplotlib's quiver in a loop efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169001/using-matplotlibs-quiver-in-a-loop-efficiently/12170760#12170760), [Visualization of 3D-numpy-array frame by frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563295/visualization-of-3d-numpy-array-frame-by-frame/11563414#11563414)