# Networkx Edge Colormap Based on Attribute

Tags: networkx

I have a graph where each edge (not nodes) has a capacity and a load. I want to draw this graph using a color map which is a gradient from blue to red, red being the most loaded and blue being the less loaded. I tried to understand the official documentation of Edge Colormap, but it doesn't help me. Can you help me?

Comment: This should help.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/17632151/13716967

Answer (score 0):

The key is to set `edge_color` to be a sequence of edges coinciding with `edgelist`, both keyword arguments of `nx.draw_networkx`. Here is a minimal working example using `pandas` and `networkx`.

```py
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

edge_df = pd.DataFrame({"source": [0, 1, 2],
                       "target": [1, 2, 0],
                       "capacity": [.1, .2, .3],
                       "load": [40, 20, 10]})

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edge_df,
                            source="source",
                            target="target",
                            edge_attr=["capacity", "load"])

nx.draw_networkx(G,
                 edgelist=list(zip(edge_df['source'], edge_df['target'])),
                 edge_color=edge_df['capacity'],
                 edge_cmap=plt.cm.bwr)
```

Should get you something like this:

[image]