# Animating a network graph to show the progress of an algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, animation, matplotlib, networkx

I would like to animate a network graph to show the progress of an algorithm. I am using NetworkX for graph creation.

From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437284/animating-network-growth-with-networkx-and-matplotlib), I came up with a solution using `clear_ouput` from `IPython.display` and the command `plt.pause()` to manage the speed of the animation. This works well for small graphs with a few nodes but when I implement on a 10x10 grid, the animation is very slow and reducing the argument in `plt.pause()` does not seem to have any effect on the animation speed. Here is a MME with an implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm where I update the colors of the nodes at each iteration of the algorithm:

```
import math
import queue
import random
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import clear_output
%matplotlib inline

# plotting function
def get_fig(G,current,pred): 
    nColorList = []
    for i in G.nodes():        
        if i == current: nColorList.append('red')
        elif i==pred: nColorList.append('white')
        elif i==N: nColorList.append('grey')        
        elif node_visited[i]==1:nColorList.append('dodgerblue')
        else: nColorList.append('powderblue')
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    nx.draw_networkx(G,pos,node_color=nColorList,width=2,node_size=400,font_size=10)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()

# graph creation
G=nx.DiGraph()
pos={}
cost={}
for i in range(100):
    x= i % 10
    y= math.floor(i/10)
    pos[i]=(x,y)    
    if i % 10 != 9 and i+1 < 100: 
       cost[(i,i+1)] = random.randint(0,9)
       cost[(i+1,i)] = random.randint(0,9)
    if i+10 < 100: 
       cost[(i,i+10)] = random.randint(0,9)
       cost[(i+10,i)] = random.randint(0,9)
G.add_edges_from(cost)   

# algorithm initialization
lab={}
path={}
node_visited={}
N = random.randint(0,99)
SE = queue.PriorityQueue()
SE.put((0,N))
for i in G.nodes():       
    if i == N: lab[i] = 0        
    else: lab[i] = 9999
    path[i] = None
    node_visited[i] = 0 

# algorithm main loop    
while not SE.empty():
    (l,j) = SE.get()    
    if node_visited[j]==1: continue
    node_visited[j] = 1
    for i in G.predecessors(j):        
        insert_in_SE = 0               
        if lab[i] > cost[(i,j)] + lab[j]:
            lab[i] = cost[(i,j)] + lab[j]
            path[i] = j
            SE.put((lab[i],i))
        clear_output(wait=True)         
        get_fig(G,j,i)
        plt.pause(0.0001)
print('end')
```

Ideally I would like to show the whole animation in no more than 5 seconds, whereas it currently takes a few minutes to complete the algorithm, which suggests that `plt.pause(0.0001)` does not work as intended.

After reading SO posts on graph animation ([post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229563/using-networkx-with-matplotlib-artistanimation) and [post 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223191/animate-drawing-networkx-edges)), it seems that the `animation` module from matplotlib could be used to resolve this but I have not been able to successfully implement the answers in my algorithm. The answer in post 2 suggests the use of `FuncAnimation` from matplotlib but I am struggling to adapt the `update` method to my problem and the answer in post 3 leads to a nice tutorial with a similar suggestion.

My question is how can I improve the speed of the animation for my problem: is it possible to arrange the `clear_output` and `plt.pause()` commands for faster animation or should I use `FuncAnimation` from matplotlib? If it's the latter, then how should I define the `update` function?

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT 1**

```
import math
import queue
import random
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# plotting function
def get_fig(G,current,pred):   
    for i in G.nodes():        
        if i==current: G.node[i]['draw'].set_color('red')            
        elif i==pred: G.node[i]['draw'].set_color('white')
        elif i==N: G.node[i]['draw'].set_color('grey')        
        elif node_visited[i]==1: G.node[i]['draw'].set_color('dodgerblue')
        else: G.node[i]['draw'].set_color('powderblue')    

# graph creation
G=nx.DiGraph()
pos={}
cost={}
for i in range(100):
    x= i % 10
    y= math.floor(i/10)
    pos[i]=(x,y)    
    if i % 10 != 9 and i+1 < 100: 
        cost[(i,i+1)] = random.randint(0,9)
        cost[(i+1,i)] = random.randint(0,9)
    if i+10 < 100: 
        cost[(i,i+10)] = random.randint(0,9)
        cost[(i+10,i)] = random.randint(0,9)
G.add_edges_from(cost)

# algorithm initialization
plt.figure(1, figsize=(10,10))
lab={}
path={}
node_visited={}
N = random.randint(0,99)
SE = queue.PriorityQueue()
SE.put((0,N))
for i in G.nodes():       
    if i == N: lab[i] = 0        
    else: lab[i] = 9999
    path[i] = None
    node_visited[i] = 0 
    G.node[i]['draw'] = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,nodelist=[i],node_size=400,alpha=1,with_labels=True,node_color='powderblue')
for i,j in G.edges():
    G[i][j]['draw']=nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=[(i,j)],width=2)    

plt.ion()
plt.draw()
plt.show()

# algorithm main loop  
while not SE.empty():
    (l,j) = SE.get()    
    if node_visited[j]==1: continue
    node_visited[j] = 1
    for i in G.predecessors(j):        
        insert_in_SE = 0               
        if lab[i] > cost[(i,j)] + lab[j]:
            lab[i] = cost[(i,j)] + lab[j]
            path[i] = j
            SE.put((lab[i],i))       
        get_fig(G,j,i)        
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.00001)
plt.close()
```

**EDIT 2**

```
import math
import queue
import random
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# graph creation
G=nx.DiGraph()
pos={}
cost={}
for i in range(100):
    x= i % 10
    y= math.floor(i/10)
    pos[i]=(x,y)    
    if i % 10 != 9 and i+1 < 100: 
        cost[(i,i+1)] = random.randint(0,9)
        cost[(i+1,i)] = random.randint(0,9)
    if i+10 < 100: 
        cost[(i,i+10)] = random.randint(0,9)
        cost[(i+10,i)] = random.randint(0,9)
G.add_edges_from(cost)

# algorithm initialization
lab={}
path={}
node_visited={}
N = random.randint(0,99)
SE = queue.PriorityQueue()
SE.put((0,N))
cf = plt.figure(1, figsize=(10,10))    
ax = cf.add_axes((0,0,1,1))
for i in G.nodes():       
    if i == N: 
        lab[i] = 0
        G.node[i]['draw'] = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,nodelist=[i],node_size=400,alpha=1.0,node_color='grey')
    else: 
        lab[i] = 9999
        G.node[i]['draw'] = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,nodelist=[i],node_size=400,alpha=0.2,node_color='dodgerblue')
    path[i] = None
    node_visited[i] = 0
for i,j in G.edges():
    G[i][j]['draw']=nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=[(i,j)],width=3,alpha=0.2,arrows=False)

plt.ion()
plt.show()
ax = plt.gca()
canvas = ax.figure.canvas
background = canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax.bbox)

# algorithm main loop  
while not SE.empty():
    (l,j) = SE.get()    
    if node_visited[j]==1: continue
    node_visited[j] = 1
    if j!=N:
        G.node[j]['draw'].set_color('r')        
    for i in G.predecessors(j):        
        insert_in_SE = 0               
        if lab[i] > cost[(i,j)] + lab[j]:
            lab[i] = cost[(i,j)] + lab[j]
            path[i] = j
            SE.put((lab[i],i))
        if i!=N:            
            G.node[i]['draw'].set_alpha(0.7)
            G[i][j]['draw'].set_alpha(1.0)
        ax.draw_artist(G[i][j]['draw'])
        ax.draw_artist(G.node[i]['draw'])
        ax.draw_artist(G.node[j]['draw'])
        canvas.blit(ax.bbox)    
        plt.pause(0.0001)
plt.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your graph isn't too big you could try the following approach that sets the properties for individual nodes and edges.  The trick is to save the output of the drawing functions which gives you a handle to the object properties like color, transparency, and visibility.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.cycle_graph(12)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

cf = plt.figure(1, figsize=(8,8))
ax = cf.add_axes((0,0,1,1))

for n in G:
    G.node[n]['draw'] = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,nodelist=[n], with_labels=False,node_size=200,alpha=0.5,node_color='r')
for u,v in G.edges():
    G[u][v]['draw']=nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=[(u,v)],alpha=0.5,arrows=False,width=5)

plt.ion()
plt.draw()

sp = nx.shortest_path(G,0,6)
edges = zip(sp[:-1],sp[1:])

for u,v in edges:
    plt.pause(1)
    G.node[u]['draw'].set_color('r')
    G.node[v]['draw'].set_color('r')
    G[u][v]['draw'].set_alpha(1.0)
    G[u][v]['draw'].set_color('r')
    plt.draw()
```

**EDIT**

Here is an example on a 10x10 grid using graphviz to do the layout.
The whole thing runs in about 1 second on my machine.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.grid_2d_graph(10,10)
pos = nx.graphviz_layout(G)

cf = plt.figure(1, figsize=(8,8))
ax = cf.add_axes((0,0,1,1))

for n in G:
    G.node[n]['draw'] = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,nodelist=[n], with_labels=False,node_size=200,alpha=0.5,node_color='k')
for u,v in G.edges():
    G[u][v]['draw']=nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=[(u,v)],alpha=0.5,arrows=False,width=5)

plt.ion()
plt.draw()
plt.show()
sp = nx.shortest_path(G,(0,0),(9,9))
edges = zip(sp[:-1],sp[1:])

for u,v in edges:
    G.node[u]['draw'].set_color('r')
    G.node[v]['draw'].set_color('r')
    G[u][v]['draw'].set_alpha(1.0)
    G[u][v]['draw'].set_color('r')
    plt.draw()
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is another approach that is faster (doesn't redraw axis or all nodes) and uses a breadth first search algorithm.  This one runs in about 2 seconds on my machine.  I noticed that some backends are faster - I'm using GTKAgg.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def single_source_shortest_path(G,source):
    ax = plt.gca()
    canvas = ax.figure.canvas
    background = canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax.bbox)
    level=0                  # the current level
    nextlevel={source:1}       # list of nodes to check at next level
    paths={source:[source]}  # paths dictionary  (paths to key from source)
    G.node[source]['draw'].set_color('r')
    G.node[source]['draw'].set_alpha('1.0')
    while nextlevel:
        thislevel=nextlevel
        nextlevel={}
        for v in thislevel:
#            canvas.restore_region(background)
            s = G.node[v]['draw']
            s.set_color('r')
            s.set_alpha('1.0')
            for w in G[v]:
                if w not in paths:
                    n = G.node[w]['draw']
                    n.set_color('r')
                    n.set_alpha('1.0')
                    e = G[v][w]['draw']
                    e.set_alpha(1.0)
                    e.set_color('k')
                    ax.draw_artist(e)
                    ax.draw_artist(n)
                    ax.draw_artist(s)
                    paths[w]=paths[v]+[w]
                    nextlevel[w]=1
                    canvas.blit(ax.bbox)
        level=level+1
    return paths



if __name__=='__main__':

    G = nx.grid_2d_graph(10,10)
    pos = nx.graphviz_layout(G)
    cf = plt.figure(1, figsize=(8,8))
    ax = cf.add_axes((0,0,1,1))

    for n in G:
        G.node[n]['draw'] = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,nodelist=[n], with_labels=False,node_size=200,alpha=0.2,node_color='k')
    for u,v in G.edges():
        G[u][v]['draw']=nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=[(u,v)],alpha=0.5,arrows=False,width=5)
    plt.ion()
    plt.show()

    path = single_source_shortest_path(G,source=(0,0))
```

Comment: I don't really see how this solution is different from mine apart that it doesn't plot inline but in a separated window and that the plotting is done after the algorithm has terminated. I have tried to implement your approach on a 10x10 grid (100 nodes) and it is as slow as mine (reducing the argument in `plt.pause()` does not work)

Comment: It's completely different actually.  You redraw the entire graph the every time through the loop and mine just updates the plot attributes which should be must faster.

Comment: I have edited the code in my question according to your suggestions. Now only the plot attributes are updated at each iteration, however, the speed improvement is only marginal: I believe that the reason for this is that in your solution with the 10x10 grid, you only plot the optimal path (edge after edge) after the algorithm has terminated, which works well and fast. But I would like to update the plot attributes **during** the searching process of the algorithm (in the Dijkstra case, each time a label is evaluated). Ideally I would also like to plot this inline.

Comment: I added another approach which uses faster canvas blitting.  Maybe that one will be fast enough for you?

Comment: This is better, thanks. I have further edited my code (see EDIT 2 block) and now it runs quite fast. One thing: after each run I receive **MatplotlibDeprecationWarning** and the kernel dies if I try to re-run (it does this with your code as well). I don't know what is GTKAgg but I have tried to use it and it makes no difference on my machine. Is there a way to fix this kernel/matplotlib issue? what about inline plotting?

Comment: Quick update: it seems that the above warning has nothing to do with the re-running problem. I removed the warning but still cannot re-run my code without restarting the kernel.

Comment: I accept your answer but it would be nice if you could advise on the kernel crashing issue.

Comment: I don't think I can help with the kernel quitting abnormally.  My example works on for me.  Maybe your plotting backend is not working correctly or the plt.close() causes some issue?