# Rendering Networkx graphs dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, graph, networkx

I am developing an application to show students various different of algorithms in action on graphs.
In order to achieve the results I was working with networkx, but did not manage to find a good way to render the graph I am working on dyamically displaying colorcoded changes, such as the next node being considered.

I was looking into mathplotlib, but most of the functions handling interactive plotting seem pretty deprecated.

Do you know of any good alternative that, ideally might even  be embedded into something like pyqt?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to do?  I think I've done the same thing you're describing using networkx.  It's just a matter of replotting with the color of specific nodes changing.

Comment: Thats a good description, yes. An example would be showing how the the Djkastra shortest path algorithm works by highlighting the nodes by changing the color based on the status. Stepping through etc are all options, but the graph does not need to be interactive, only dynamically updated

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815454/animate-graph-diffusion-with-networkx?rq=1  You can also redraw the figure at each step and save it without using the animation routines.  The important details are that you create `pos` in advance, and then at each step you redraw noting that it is possible to draw different nodes with different colors.