# How to use an update function to animate a NetworkX graph in Matplotlib 2.0.0?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I'm trying to figure out how to animate my `networkx` graphs using `matplotlib 2.0` and the `animation` module inside of it.  I saw [Using NetworkX with matplotlib.ArtistAnimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229563/using-networkx-with-matplotlib-artistanimation) and [Animate graph diffusion with NetworkX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815454/animate-graph-diffusion-with-networkx) but I can't figure out how these update functions work even with the pseudocode.

I'm trying to step through a sequence of letters (nodes) and then plot the path from the origin `"O"` to the current step.  It will make more sense looking at the plots below.  I don't want to have to render them out to make an `.mp4` outside of `Python 3.6`.  I think it would be a good resource for people to understand how these update functions operate and how they can be applied to visualizing networks.

**How can I use an `update function` to animate my `networkx` graph below?**

Obviously the animation wouldn't be on a `matplotlib figure` with different `ax` objects but this is just to illustrate how the frames would be laid out.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.animation as animation


def update_func(num, data, line):
    # https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/examples/animation/basic_example.html
    line.set_data(data[..., :num])
    return line

# Create Graph
np.random.seed(2)
G = nx.cubical_graph()
G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, {0:"O", 1:"X", 2:"XZ", 3:"Z", 4:"Y", 5:"YZ", 6: "XYZ", 7:"XY"})
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

# Sequence of letters
sequence_of_letters = "".join(['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z']) #np.random.RandomState(0).choice(list("XYZ"), size=6, replace=True)
idx_colors = sns.cubehelix_palette(5, start=.5, rot=-.75)[::-1]
idx_weights = [3,2,1]

# General graph structure
with plt.style.context("seaborn-white"):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True, ax=ax)
    print(ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim())
# (-0.10500000000000001, 1.105) (-0.088398066788676247, 0.93028441715702148)

# Build plot
with plt.style.context("seaborn-white"):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=2, figsize=(10,5))
    for i in range(0, len(sequence_of_letters), 3):
        triad = sequence_of_letters[i:i+3]
        for j in range(1,4):
            # Axes index for rows and cols
            idx = i + j - 1
            row_idx, col_idx = {True: (0,idx), False: (1,idx - 3)}[idx < 3]
            ax = axes[row_idx][col_idx]

            # Path in Graph
            path = ["O"] + ["".join(sorted(set(triad[:k + 1]))) for k in range(j)]

           # Background nodes
            nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos, ax=ax, edge_color="gray")
            null_nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=pos, nodelist=set(G.nodes()) - set(path), node_color="white",  ax=ax)
            null_nodes.set_edgecolor("black")

            # Query nodes
            query_nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=pos, nodelist=path, node_color=idx_colors[:len(path)], ax=ax)
            query_nodes.set_edgecolor("white")
            nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos=pos, labels=dict(zip(path,path)),  font_color="white", ax=ax)
            edgelist = [path[k:k+2] for k in range(len(path) - 1)]
            nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos, edgelist=edgelist, width=idx_weights[:len(path)], ax=ax)

            # Scale plot ax
            ax.set_title("Frame %d:    "%(idx+1) +  " - ".join(path), fontweight="bold")
            ax.set_xlim((-0.10500000000000001, 1.105))
            ax.set_ylim((-0.088398066788676247, 0.93028441715702148))
            ax.set_xticks([])
            ax.set_yticks([])
```

[image]

Comment: If you want a canonical answer, you need to provide a canoncial problem. The problem you show here is much too specific for a canonical answer on animating a networkx graph. In contrast, the answers from both linked questions actually are quite general and applicable also here.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The answers to both linked question provide very good examples on how to animate a networkx graph. They are much more canonical than any answer the example code in this question would allow for.

I therefore focus here on the question of how to use an update function to animate the networkx graph from the question.

The solution is to put everything that is in the two for-loops into a function, which takes at least one index as argument. One can then use this index to generate the image.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn.apionly as sns
import matplotlib.animation

# Create Graph
np.random.seed(2)
G = nx.cubical_graph()
G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, {0:"O", 1:"X", 2:"XZ", 3:"Z", 4:"Y", 5:"YZ", 6: "XYZ", 7:"XY"})
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

# Sequence of letters
sequence_of_letters = "".join(['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z'])
idx_colors = sns.cubehelix_palette(5, start=.5, rot=-.75)[::-1]
idx_weights = [3,2,1]

# Build plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))


def update(num):
    ax.clear()
    i = num // 3
    j = num % 3 + 1
    triad = sequence_of_letters[i:i+3]
    path = ["O"] + ["".join(sorted(set(triad[:k + 1]))) for k in range(j)]

    # Background nodes
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos, ax=ax, edge_color="gray")
    null_nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=pos, nodelist=set(G.nodes()) - set(path), node_color="white",  ax=ax)
    null_nodes.set_edgecolor("black")

    # Query nodes
    query_nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=pos, nodelist=path, node_color=idx_colors[:len(path)], ax=ax)
    query_nodes.set_edgecolor("white")
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos=pos, labels=dict(zip(path,path)),  font_color="white", ax=ax)
    edgelist = [path[k:k+2] for k in range(len(path) - 1)]
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos, edgelist=edgelist, width=idx_weights[:len(path)], ax=ax)

    # Scale plot ax
    ax.set_title("Frame %d:    "%(num+1) +  " - ".join(path), fontweight="bold")
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])


ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=6, interval=1000, repeat=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I thought you had to use the `fargs` during each frame.  Apologies for claiming this was canonical.  I thought it could be a good resource b/c I haven't found many examples that update the nodes in this way.

Comment: I'm sure it is a good resource for people doing exactly this kind of animation. Of course you could calculate the path and edgelist for each frame prior to animation, store them in a list and provide them as extra arguments to the updating function, using `fargs`; this just seems more complicated to me.