# Making animation on matplotlib of graph with Networkx efficiently

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib, animation, networkx

I am trying to animate a graph whose edges widths and color change over time. My code works, but it is extremely slow. I imagine there are more efficient implementations.

```
def minimal_graph(datas, pos):
    frames = len(datas[0])
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)
    axes = axes.flatten()
    for j, dat in enumerate(datas):
        G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(dat[0])
        nx.draw(G, pos, ax=axes[j])
    def update(it, data, pos, ax):
        print(it)
        for i, dat in enumerate(data):
            # This is the problematic line, because I clear the axis hence
            # everything has to be drawn from scratch every time.
            ax[i].clear()
            G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(dat[it])
            edges, weights = zip(*nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight').items())
            nx.draw(
                G,
                pos,
                node_color='#24FF00',
                edgelist=edges,
                edge_color=weights,
                width=weights,
                edge_vmin=-5,
                edge_vmax=5,
                ax=ax[i])
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=frames, fargs=(
        datas, pos, axes), interval=100)
    ani.save('temp/graphs.mp4')
    plt.close()


dataset1 = []
dataset2 = []
for i in range(100):
    arr1 = np.random.rand(400, 400)
    arr2 = np.random.rand(400, 400)
    dataset1.append(arr1)
    dataset2.append(arr2)

datasets = [dataset1, dataset2]
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(dataset1[0])
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

minimal_graph(datasets, pos)
```

As pointed out in the code, the problem is that at every frame I redraw the graph from "scratch". When using animations in matplotlib, I usually try to create lines and use the function '''line.set_data()''', which I know is a lot faster. It's just that I don't know how to set that for a graph using networkx. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646550/how-to-use-an-update-function-to-animate-a-networkx-graph-in-matplotlib-2-0-0) question here, but they also use the same `ax.clear` and redraw everything for every frame. So, is there a way to set a line object to not redraw everything every iteration? For example, in my case the nodes are always the same (color, location, size stay the same).

Comment: You have 400 nodes. However, if -- as your example data suggests -- the graphs are fully connected, then you have 160 000 edges. If all of them have to be redrawn on each iteration (as your code suggests), there really isn't much time to be gained by keeping the node artists constant and only redrawing the edge artists.

Comment: Not all edges are connected. In fact, it is very sparse. Typically I have around 1000-2000 edges.

Comment: Does the adjacency remain constant (even if the weights change)?

Comment: Yes. Only the weights change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nx.draw` does not expose the matplotlib artists used to represent the nodes and edges, so you cannot alter the properties of the artists in-place. Technically, if you plot the edges separately, you do get some collection of artists back but it is non-trivial to map the list of artists back to the edges, [in particular if there are self-loops present](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/5106).

If you are open for using other libraries to make the animation, I wrote [netgraph](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph) some time ago. Crucially to your problem, it exposes all artists in easily to index forms such that their properties can be altered in-place and without redrawing everything else. `netgraph` accepts both full-rank matrices and `networkx` `Graph` objects as inputs so it should be simple to feed in your data.

Below is a simple example visualization. If I run the same script with with 400 nodes and 1000 edges, it needs 30 seconds to complete on my laptop.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
MWE for animating edges.
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from netgraph import Graph # pip install netgraph
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

total_nodes = 10
total_frames = 100

adjacency_matrix = np.random.rand(total_nodes, total_nodes) < 0.2
weight_matrix = 5 * np.random.randn(total_frames, total_nodes, total_nodes)

# precompute normed weight matrix, such that weights are on the interval [0, 1];
# weights can then be passed directly to matplotlib colormaps (which expect float on that interval)
vmin, vmax = -5, 5
weight_matrix[weight_matrix<vmin] = vmin
weight_matrix[weight_matrix>vmax] = vmax
weight_matrix -= vmin
weight_matrix /= vmax - vmin

cmap = plt.cm.RdGy

plt.ion()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
g = Graph(adjacency_matrix, arrows=True, ax=ax)

def update(ii):
    artists = []
    for jj, kk in zip(*np.where(adjacency_matrix)):
        w = weight_matrix[ii, jj, kk]
        g.edge_artists[(jj, kk)].set_facecolor(cmap(w))
        g.edge_artists[(jj, kk)].width = 0.01 * np.abs(w-0.5) # assuming large negative edges should be wide, too
        g.edge_artists[(jj, kk)]._update_path()
        artists.append(g.edge_artists[(jj, kk)])
    return artists

animation = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=total_frames, interval=100, blit=True)
animation.save('edge_animation.mp4')
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to pass node positions to the Graph object? I was looking at the documentation, and didn't quite find it.

Comment: Sure. Use the argument `node_layout`, which is either a `dict` that maps nodes to (x, y) tuples or a string specifying a layout algorithm. So you could use: `Graph(adjacency_matrix, node_layout={0 : (0.1, 0.2), 1 : (0.3, 0.4), ...}, arrows=True, ax=ax)`.