# animate network graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, matplotlib-animation

I would like to draw a dynamic network to show how it changes over time as new observations are added.
I've found how to animate a network given two single states (here called *s_pos*, *t_pos*), but what i'm looking for goes a little further, as I would like to populate my network row by row.
I imagine that I need to update G by iterating through my dataframe within the function anim(t); which I struggle to achieve.

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ["2022-11-28", "2022-11-29", "2022-11-30", "2022-12-01"],
                   'ID' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A'],
                   'Value': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Z']})

# network
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='ID', target='Value')

# two states as an example
s_pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
t_pos = nx.circular_layout(G)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))

# animation function with smooth interpolation between states
def anim(t):
    global s_pos
    global t_pos
    interpolation = {i: s_pos[i]*(1-t/299) + t_pos[i] * t/299  for i in list(t_pos.keys())}
    plt.clf()
    plt.cla()
    nx.draw(G, pos=interpolation,
            with_labels=True,
            node_size = 5000)

    

# run and save
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, anim, repeat=False, frames=300, interval=20)
f = r'path\network.gif'
writergif = animation.PillowWriter(fps=30) 
ani.save(f, writer=writergif)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly that you would like to have your network progressively (row by row) appear in your animation, one way to do that would be to create a new network `Gt` in the `anim` function based on the rows of the dataframe up to `t`. At each step of the animation, you can also clear the plot with `ax.clear()` as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646550/how-to-use-an-update-function-to-animate-a-networkx-graph-in-matplotlib-2-0-0).

See example below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ["2022-11-28", "2022-11-29", "2022-11-30", "2022-12-01"],
                   'ID' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A'],
                   'Value': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Z']})

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='ID', target='Value') # create full graph G for reference
s_pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
t_pos = nx.circular_layout(G)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))

# animation function with smooth interpolation between states
def anim(t):
    Gt=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.iloc[0:t], source='ID', target='Value') #create graph based n the row of the data frame up to t
    interpolation = {i: s_pos[i]*(1-t/299) + t_pos[i] * t/299  for i in list(t_pos.keys())}
    ax.clear() #clear axes
    nx.draw(Gt, pos=interpolation,with_labels=True,node_size = 500,ax=ax)
    ax.set_xlim([-1.5,1.5])
    ax.set_ylim([-1.5,1.5])
    

# run and save
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, anim, repeat=False, frames=300, interval=100)
plt.show()
```

[image]